# insert records except in sql server

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, sql-server-2016

I have two tables t1 and t2.
      t1 having 10k records and t2 having 2k records. The 2k records of t2 is present in t1.
      I wanted the 8k different records from t1 which is not present in t2.

I'm doing this as below:

```
select id, second_telphon from t1
except 
select id, second_telphon from t2
```

However, I'm still getting all the 10k records. Is "except" keyword not working?

how can I achieve this?

Comment: is there any unique column in the table which idetifies weather they are duplicate or not

Comment: Except does work, but without seeing your table definitions (including collation) then it's not possible to guess why it isn't working for you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can perform a Join to get the unique data from the tables .

like the tables t1 & t2 both you cna perform left or right join .

example:

```
SELECT T1.*
    FROM T1
    WHERE NOT EXISTS(SELECT NULL
                         FROM T2
                         WHERE T1.ID = T2.ID 
                             AND T1.Date = T2.Date
                             AND T1.Hour = T2.Hour)


OR .


SELECT T1.*
    FROM T1
        LEFT JOIN T2
            ON T1.ID = T2.ID
                AND T1.Date = T2.Date
                AND T1.Hour = T2.Hour
    WHERE T2.ID IS NULL
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
SELECT * 
FROM T1
WHERE NOT EXISTS(SELECT id,second_telphon FROM t2)
```

If ID is a unique value, Try this also:

```
SELECT * 
FROM T1
WHERE ID NOT IN(SELECT ID FROM t2)
```

Answer (score 0):

You could try a union, followed by an aggregation to restrict to those records in the first table which were not duplicated by the second table:

```
SELECT id, second_telphon
FROM
(
    SELECT id, second_telphon FROM t1
    UNION ALL
    SELECT id, second_telphon FROM t2
) t
GROUP BY id, second_telphon
HAVING COUNT(*) = 1;
```

If a record, being defined as an `id`, `second_telphon` pair, has a record count of only one after the union, it implies that this record was unique to the first table.

Answer (score 0):

Just do left join

```
    select t1.id,t1.second_telphon  from t1 
       left  join  t2 on 
       t1.id  = t2.id  
      and  t1.second_telphon =t2.second_telphon
   where t2.id   is null
```